# Which version of Project 2010 is required for SP2010 Enterprise for Internet Sites?

Tags: 2010, sync, ms-project

Do I have to buy Project 2010 Server License so run on SharePoint 2010 Enterprise for Internet Sites?

I need to know the exact version I need to buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Project 2010 Server is something like hybrid of MS Project and SharePoint. It has functionality of SharePoint and some OOTB feature to work with MS Project. You can learn more on official site: [http://www.microsoft.com/project](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en-us/project-server-2010.aspx)